# caroufredsel Cool carousel 51 with four images

Tags: carousel, caroufredsel

**[I want to use this script](http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/51/coolcarousel.html)**

But with 4 images :

[image]

I can not find how to do
What options should I use with fredcarousel
can you refer me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here's a breakdown of what's going on in this carouFredsel example:

The author specifies the position of each element in the slideshow using variables:

```
var _center = {
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    marginLeft: 0,
    marginTop: 0,
    marginRight: 0
};
var _left = {
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    marginLeft: 0,
    marginTop: 150,
    marginRight: -150
};
var _right = {
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    marginLeft: -150,
    marginTop: 150,
    marginRight: 0
};
var _outLeft = {
    width: 150,
    height: 100,
    marginLeft: 150,
    marginTop: 200,
    marginRight: -200
};
var _outRight = {
    width: 150,
    height: 100,
    marginLeft: -200,
    marginTop: 200,
    marginRight: 50
};
```

And then uses the carouFredSel initiator to customize the scroll behavior:

```
$('#carousel').carouFredSel({
    width: 900,
    height: 400,
    align: false,
    items: {
        visible: 3,
        width: 100
    },
    scroll: {
        items: 1,
        duration: 400,
        onBefore: function( data ) {
            data.items.old.eq( 0 ).animate(_outLeft);
            data.items.visible.eq( 0 ).animate(_left);
            data.items.visible.eq( 1 ).animate(_center);
            data.items.visible.eq( 2 ).animate(_right).css({ zIndex: 1 });
            data.items.visible.eq( 2 ).next().css(_outRight).css({ zIndex: 0 });

            setTimeout(function() {
                data.items.old.eq( 0 ).css({ zIndex: 1 });
                data.items.visible.eq( 0 ).css({ zIndex: 2 });
                data.items.visible.eq( 1 ).css({ zIndex: 3 });
                data.items.visible.eq( 2 ).css({ zIndex: 2 });
            }, 200);
        }
    }
});
```

The onBefore event receives a number of different parameters containing current information about the slideshow. In this case, the first parameter is `oldItems`, and then using the previously set "positions" (`var _center`, `var _left`, etc), the script animates the items to correspond.
These lines then set the css & z-index of the elements in the slideshow, after animation. It allows the slideshow to select the elements based on their css properties in a more efficient manner.

```
$('#carousel').children().eq( 0 ).css(_left).css({ zIndex: 2 });
$('#carousel').children().eq( 1 ).css(_center).css({ zIndex: 3 });
$('#carousel').children().eq( 2 ).css(_right).css({ zIndex: 2 });
$('#carousel').children().eq( 3 ).css(_outRight).css({ zIndex: 1 });
```

To adapt this to 4 elements, you'll need to add a 5th variable with positioning and a name like `_farRight` and plug that into the script at each step.